# Range object returns empty values

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set range to a variable in this fashion:

```
Dim srcRng As Range
Set srcRng = Range(hrwb.Worksheets(1).Range(yomColAddress)(1).Address, _
Cells(hrwb.Worksheets(1).Range(yomColAddress).row + 200, rightMostCol)(1).Address)
```

for some weird reason when I call

```
srcRng(1) 'actually instead of 1 is i that runs 1 to srcRng.Count
```

it doesn't return the upper leftmost cell value. Any ideas why?

(for those who are not familiar with this technique: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/cells.htm)

**Informations:**

at execution time the variables `yomColAddress=$AL$9` and `righMostCol=40`

`hrwb.Worksheets(1).Range(yomColAddress)(1)` works as expected.

With `MsgBox srcRng(1).Address & " value:" & srcRng(1).Value` I get "`$AL$9 value:`"

The value of `AL9` is the text "`yom`"

The actual **code** is:

```
Dim srcRng As Range
Set srcRng = Range(hrwb.Worksheets(1).Range(yomColAddress)(1).Address, Cells(hrwb.Worksheets(1).Range(yomColAddress).row + 200, rightMostCol)(1).Address)
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
While (weekDayCol = 0 And i <= srcRng.count)
    If loneHebDayLetter("à", "ä", srcRng(i)) Then'loneHebDayLetter checks some conditions on a cell
        weekDayCol = srcRng(i).Column
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

Comment: Can you give some more infos about the values of `yomColAddress` and `rightMostCol`, just in case. Do you just call `srcRng(1)` like that? (I don't think so ...)

Comment: smagnan I just edited the question in response to you. Thank You.

Comment: What do you get if you do `Debug.Print srcRng(1).Address` (or `MsgBox srcRng(1).Address`? Sorry for all the questions but the point is to get a better idea of what happens ...

Comment: when I execute 'MsgBox srcRng(1).Address & " value:" & srcRng(1).Value' I get "$AL$9 value: " , I suspect that the issue is something with the assigning of the range to the variable ... Your question are very welcome!

Comment: Mmmmh two (last I hope ^^) questions: 1./ Can you add your actual code where you use `srcRng`, the relevant part at least 2./ Some more infos about your worksheet like: value in the AL9 cell etc  ...

Comment: @smagnan edited for you.. the hrwb workbook mostly contains text values. any further clarifications requests are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get what goes wrong here:

The code itself is working well but **not** on the good data (This is a supposition but I just did some tests with a custom workbook)

### Short version

Just add `srcRng.Select` after `Set srcRng` (no real interest but to understand what it does) and I think you will get what happens if my supposition is correct.

### Longer version

When you do `Set srcRng = ...` it does create the correct *Range* but it is not linked to any *sheet* actually ... It just means remember a *Range* which goes from *cell X* to *cell Y*.

**The point is:** The sheet (let's say *"sheet2"*) where your code is executed isn't the same as the one where the datas are (say *"sheet1"*) so `srcRng(1)` is understood as `Sheets("sheet2").srcRng(1)` instead of `Sheets("sheet1").srcRng(1)` (<- that's what you want)

Even if not elegant, **this should work**:

```
Dim srcRng As Range
With hrwb.Worksheets(1)
    Set srcRng = Range(.Range(yomColAddress)(1).Address, Cells(.Range(yomColAddress).row + 200, rightMostCol)(1).Address)
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    While (weekDayCol = 0 And i <= srcRng.count)
        If loneHebDayLetter("à", "ä", .Range(srcRng.Address)(i).Value) Then 'I assume it take the value not the cell: if it take the cell you may get an error!
            weekDayCol = srcRng(i).Column
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End With
```

What is important is the use of `.Range(srcRng.Address)(i).Value` to access the value in the right worksheet! (That's why this trick is not needed here: `srcRng(i).Column` because colum numbers do not change from one sheet to an other)

(*NOTE: I used `with` to optimize/clarify the code*)

If something isn't clear tell me

Comment: I knew it is something with the range assigning: instead of Set srcRng = Range(hrwb.Worksheets(1).Range.....) I wrote Set srcRng = hrwb.Worksheets(1).Range(hrwb.Worksheets(1).Range.....) and it works perfectly now! Thank You so much for your explanation and devotion!

Comment: No problem, always a pleasure to help (: